# VBA Convert Datetime to Hour in a Column

Tags: vba, excel, datetime, type-conversion

i wanted to Convert the Datetime values in one Column to just Hour Values. Now I tried it with a loop but I get the error saying that the Types are incompatible. Any Idea?

```
Dim l As Range
For Each l In Hour.Range("A1", "A" & lngLastRow)
If l.Value <> "" Then l.Value = Hour(l.Value)
Next
```

Comment: Without seeing the data, my guess is that you have strings instead of dates in the cells.

Comment: That coul actually be the Problem, is it possible to use CDate for example inside the Hour Function?

Comment: But it actually works with Hour(A2) when I do it manualy, I mean outside the VBA code, so I guess i do have it in the right format.

Comment: I would use `Hour(CDbl(l.value))`  Does the formula work all the way down the column?  Does it return an error in any one of the cells?  When the code errors what is the value of `l.Value`?

Comment: Yes manualy it works all the way down. Hour(CDbl(l.value)) doesnt work, still same Error, the Data in the Cells look like this: 12.07.2017  21:14:51

Comment: If it works all the way try: `Hour(l.Value2)`

Comment: Still dont work, same error

Comment: put `msgbox l.value2` before the If statement. note the values in the msgbox.  What is the value in the msgbox, right before it errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of all the possible names in the world, did you really named your Worksheet **Hour** or am I wrong?

If this is the case, simply rename the worksheet, it would automatically fix everything and thus you would be happy. And never use names like `Minute`, `Hour`, `Second`, `Integer` for any variable or object.

This is a possible solution then:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Testing()

    Dim l               As Range
    Dim lngLastrow      As Long: lngLastrow = 6

    For Each l In ActiveSheet.Range("A1", "A" & lngLastrow)
        If l <> "" Then
            l.Offset(0, 1) = Format(l, "HH")
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Make sure to change the name here, not on the tab:

[image]